# Printing on "Send to Microsoft OneNote" printer does nothing

Tags: windows-10, pdf, printing, microsoft-onenote-2010

I wanted to add a PDF document to my One Note notebook as a note. I have very little experience with using OneNote but I have the same accounts on my PC and on my Windows phone, so it seemed to me as a fast and obvious choice to share a document.
I have clicked on print and selected the "Send to OneNote 2010" printer and clicked on Print and the PDF was printed OK, but cannot find the printed PDF anywhere in my notebooks.

Where is it and how do I find it?

Comment: If you selected "Send to OneNote 2010" and already have a notebook setup it should have started OneNote and then prompted you for the location you wanted to send it to.  So where you find it depends on your selection, it does not appear in any notebook, until you make that selection.

Comment: I see, so the printer does not work probably after win 10 upgrade.

Comment: Well considering I use both `OneNote 2010` and `OneNote 2013` on Windows 10 and use this feature often I say its more likely this is problem is unique to your system.  If it isn't working I suggest you reinstall both `OneNote 2010` and `OneNote 2013`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out my problem.

When I tried to print printer's test page, OneNote showed me this error:

> Before you can use this feature, OneNote must start for the first
>   time.

When I tried printing from Adobe Reader DC, it showed no error and just printed the page to nowhere.

I had already run OneNote, but the latest version that comes automatically with Windows (I have Windows 10).
But this driver points to the other older OneNote 2010, so I have run this older OneNote 2010 app once and now I am able to print from Adobe Reader DC to OneNote 2010.

I was not really aware that I have now two versions of OneNote installed after the upgrade to Windows 10, since I do not use it much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it.  Here are the instructions:

1. Use the appropriate program to open the document or file that you want to import into OneNote. For example, use Microsoft Office Word to open documents or Microsoft Office Excel to open Excel workbooks.
2. On the File menu, click Print.

   **Note:** Some third-party programs might have different interfaces than the Windows interface. Print commands may have different names and may be in different locations than the commands described in these steps.
3. In the Print dialog box, select Send to OneNote as the printer, and then click Print.  OneNote does not maintain a link to the source file. If the source file is updated, those changes do not appear in your notebook unless you import the file again.

   **Note:** When you print a file to OneNote by using the OneNote print driver, a copy of the file's contents is imported.

[Click here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830047) for addition info, it's Microsoft's KB also you can watch this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tccm0AWtJRk).  I hope this helps.

Comment: That is what I did, seems that the driver is not working properly for me.

Answer (score -1):

On the Windows taskbar, click the Start button or windows button(in win 8 or 10).
in win 8 & 10 type control panel and click Control Panel.
When Control Panel opens, click View Devices and Printers. click Devices and Printers.
you can see that onenote has set as default printer.
Right-click the printer icon that represents your physical printer or other printer you want to use, and then click Set as Default Printer on the shortcut menu.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.